# dotnet-/usr/local/bin/dotnet does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core

I have downloaded .NET Core 3.1 SDK (v3.1.300) on my Mac Catalina 10.15.5.

I was running a small X-Unit test case on Visual Studio. I am getting the below error. I researched and tried all the recommended suggestions I have found on here, but still did not solve the problem. Could someone help me here?

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-/usr/local/bin/dotnet does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the unit test, as well as how you are running the test?

Comment: was following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-test-deploy-azure-functions-with-visual-studio/6-unit-test-azure-functions

Comment: I think it would be easier to find a solution if you try and simplify the problem. In a terminal (not Visual Studio), does a `dotnet --info` do anything? What about `dotnet new console -o TestApplication2`? Can you then `cd TestApplication2` and `dotnet run` it?

Comment: @omajid  botnet info gives me Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/, but the program seems like looking to this path dotnet-/usr/local/bin/dotnet in above 2nd bulletin. With those common, I can successfully run to Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh

The above is installed to below in the official Jenkins Docker container:

```
root@9c0421a1da57:~# pwd
/root
root@9c0421a1da57:~# cd .dotnet
root@9c0421a1da57:~/.dotnet# ls -atl
total 136
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1116 Mar 13 22:10 LICENSE.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73048 Mar 13 22:10 dotnet
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31330 Mar 13 22:10 ThirdPartyNotices.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 templates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 shared
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 sdk
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 packs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 host
drwx------ 1 root root  4096 Mar 13 22:10 ..
```

Answer (score -1):

`dotnet-/usr/local/bin/dotnet`

there should be a space after the first `dotnet`

`dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet`

Comment: Any idea how the default download happened like that? And how do I fix that?

Comment: If this solution is right, then the "fix" is to run the dotnet vm (`dotnet`) and ask it to run itself (`/usr/local/bin/dotnet`). That can't be right...